# OpenCL "cross"-compile x64 / 32-bit-pointer GPU

Tags: opencl, cross-compiling

I'm trying to optimize my kernel functions and ran into a bit of an issue. First, this may be Radeon R9 (Hawaii) related, but it should happen for other GPU devices as well.

---

For the host I have two platform options. Either compile and run as an x86-program, or run as an x64-program. Depending which platform I chose, I get different compiled kernels. One that uses 32-bit pointers and pointer arithmetic, and the other that uses 64-bit pointers. The generated IL code shows the difference, in the first case it is

```
prog kernel &__OpenCL_execute_kernel(
  kernarg_u32 %_.global_offset_0,
  kernarg_u32 %_.global_offset_1,  
  ...
```

and in the second case it is:

```
prog kernel &__OpenCL_execute_kernel(
  kernarg_u64 %_.global_offset_0,
  kernarg_u64 %_.global_offset_1,  
  ...
```

64-bit arithmetic on a GPU is rather expensive and consumes a lot of additional VGPRs. In my case, the 64-bit pointer version requires 8 VGPRs more and has about 140 VALUInsts more, as shown by CodeXL. Performance overall is about 37% worse in my case between the slower 64-bit and the faster 32-bit kernel code. Which is, other than internal pointer arithmetic, completely identical. I have tried to optimize this, but even with plain offsets I'm still stuck with a lot of ADD_U64 IL-instructions, which in ISA-code produce two instructions: V_ADD_I32 and V_ADDC_U32. And of course all pointers require double private memory space (hence more VGPRs).

---

**Now my question is: Is there a way to "cross"-compile an OpenCL kernel so a x64-program can create a 32-bit-pointer kernel?** I don't need to address that much memory in the GPU, so addressing less than 4 GiB of memory space is fine. As my host is also executing AVX-512 instructions with all 32 zmm registers, which is only available in x64 mode, an x86-program is not an option. That makes the whole situation a bit challenging.

Well, my fallback solution is to spawn a x86-child process that uses shared memory and acts as a compiling gate. But I'd rather not do that if a simple flag or (AMD specific) setting in OpenCL does the trick.

---

*Please don't reply with a why-that-is-response. I'm completely aware why the x64-program and kernel behave that way.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using as host CPU, that supports AVX-512?

Comment: that's an Intel Xeon Phi 7230 (Knights Landing)

Comment: OpenCL kernels (inside the GPU) run exactly the same code, weather the host is 64/32. You can't loose 37% performance just by using 64bits. Also datatypes are perfectly clear about the size of the pointers. Are you sure you are not using some loose defined data type for the buffers? And thus making them bigger in the 64bits case? Just guessing

Comment: No. When the host is x64 then the kernel uses flat memory instructions with 64-bit pointers (FLAT_LOAD_UBYTE) [see chapter 9 of ISA instruction manual]. When the host is x86 then the kernel uses buffer memory instructions (BUFFER_LOAD_UBYTE). You can check the difference in CodeXL static code analysis with "32-bit GPU Build" vs "64-bit GPU Build". Performance loss is due to more required VGPRs with reduced max waves (8 down to 6). And of course more ALU instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I've a couple ideas, but not being familiar with the guts of the AMD GPU OpenCL implementation, I am stabbing in the dark.

1. Can you pass the data in via an image (even if it's not)?  On Intel GPUs going through the sampler provides a different path and can avoid 64-bit arithmetic even in the 64-bit version.
2. Does AMD have an extension that allows you to block read and write?  This can help if the compiler proves that the address is uniform (scalar). E.g. something like [Intel Subgroups](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/intel/cl_intel_subgroups.txt) (which enable some block IO).  On Intel this helps avoid shipping a SIMD's worth of addresses across the bus for a scatter/gather (and saves register space too).
3. (This is a stretch.) Does compiling for OpenCL 1.2 or lower help? That is, specify `-cl-std=CL1.2`? If the compiler knows that SVM is not being used (>=OpenCL 2.0) and were to run a conservative analysis on the program to prove that it's not doing something wild with pointer arithmetic, it could feasibly do arithmetic in 32-bit and implicitly add a 64-bit relative offset to all addresses (making the GPU program think that it's using 32-bit addresses).

Again, I know nothing about AMD specifics, but I feel your pain with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

1. I did a test with images instead of buffers. This has a serious performance impact, my kernel time is up from 0.7000 µsec to 1.1000 µsec. I have to look into this, the register pressure is less. Maybe that's part of the solution.
2. No extension or option that I found.
3. Has no effect. Any other compiler option, either AMD specific or generic, has no effect at all.

I started a support request with AMD, they look into it. I'm using a compiler gate now, spawning an x86 process that does OpenCL compiling and processing. And it works quite well at the moment.